# C# Compilation without visual studio

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, command-line-interface

I am learning C# and I know the advantages and ease of using Visual Studio but basically I want to learn the mechanics of C# the old school way.
I understand that I need to the least .NET Framework and Notepad to compile C# code which I have already. Now I have created the small app as myApp.cs and I want to know how should I compile it as executable from command line cmd.exe

Comment: Added some extra relevant tags

Comment: Download a decent editor.  Notepad is just about the worst thing to write code in.  Try Notepad++, its free (both meanings).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The command line compiler is **csc.exe**.

MSDN has [an article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379563%28VS.80%29.aspx) that might help get you started.

Comment: What's the difference between .NET Framework and .NET Framework SDK?
MSDN Article mention .NET Framework SDK and I see that I have .NET Framework all  of the versions from 1.1 to 3.5 SP1 and yes the folder does contain the csc.exe

Comment: The .NET Framework is the runtime, and the SDK is the Software Development Kit for the runtime. It has extra things like disassemblers, a debugger, code-signing tools, tools for manipulating the Global Assembly Cache, and so on.

Answer (score 4):

csc.exe is the compiler.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78f4aasd.aspx

Answer (score 3):

It is actually very easy to run the **csc.exe** compiler outside of the IDE but the trick is to make sure you have first run the [vsvars32.bat](http://www.zeusedit.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1235) file. This batch file sets up all the *environment variables* required by the compiler.

And while you're at it you can even debug the program outside the IDE by using the [standalone debugger](http://www.zeusedit.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=2507).

Answer (score 1):

http://www.devsource.com/c/a/Using-VS/Working-at-the-Visual-Studio-Command-Line/

That should help. It describes how to command line compile using the Visual Studio tools

Answer (score 0):

[nAnt](http://nant.sourceforge.net/) and [msbuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k6kkbsd.aspx) are a couple of other utilities that may be useful beyond just the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Good idea, I think it can help with understanding what is going on.

Using csc:

The /recurse flag is really useful and can be used to compile all files in a directory tree.

If you want to make life a little bit easier for yourself while still staying close to the basics use a nicer text editor than notepad. One that can call a batch file that compiles and runs your program. Then you can set it up so that when you click on a compile error it goes to the source code for that error.